# Remove cell when button pressed inside cell CustomTableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

Hi I'm trying to remove the cell when the checkbox is selected but the function keeps removing cell at index 0 instead of selected cell index

**Set up Cell with tag**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.tag = indexPath.row


    print("The tag is \(cell.tag)")
```

**CustomTableViewCell**

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
func RadioTapped(_ tag: Int)


}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell  {

var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

@IBOutlet var radioButton: BEMCheckBox!
@IBOutlet var taskText: UILabel!
@IBAction func radioTapped(_ sender: UIView){
    delegate?.RadioTapped(sender.tag)
}
```

**Function called when radiobutton is tapped**

```
func RadioTapped(_ tag: Int) {
    print("Radio Tapped at \(tag)")
}
```

RadioTapped always print "Radio tapped at 0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your immediate issue is the line:

```
delegate?.RadioTapped(sender.tag)
```

It should be:

```
delegate?.RadioTapped(tag)
```

Since it is the cell's tag being set.

But do not use tags for this. Update the cell's delegate method to pass itself as the parameter. Then the delegate can determine the cell's indexPath from the table view.

Updated protocol:

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func radioTapped(_ cell: TableViewCell)
}
```

Updated cell tap handler:

```
@IBAction func radioTapped(_ sender: UIView){
    delegate?.radioTapped(self)
}
```

Updated `cellForRowAt:`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
cell.delegate = self
```

Update delegate method in the table view:

```
func radioTapped(_ cell: TableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        print("Radio Tapped at \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should I not use tags? Are they bad practice?

Comment: Yes, using tags is a very bad practice. Unfortunately they are used a lot but they should not. They fail miserably due to cell reuse, especially if rows can be inserted, deleted, or moved within the table view.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting tag for cell but accessing tag of button so set cell's button tag.

```
cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
```