# Swift 5 how to delete and copy tableview cell by using button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

how to delete and copy tableview cell by using button

```
var dataAry:[Section] = Section.modelArray()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {

    if let indexPathForSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
        indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false) 
        view.isHidden = true

        return nil
    }
    view.isHidden = false

    return indexPath
    }


@IBAction func didTapDeleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {
   print("didTapDeleteBtn")

   let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
   "tableviewcell".remove(at: 0)
   tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
   tableView.reloadData()

}
@IBAction func didTapCopyBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        print("didTapCopyBtn")
}
```

button will show inside the view

this only deleted the first row of the tableviewcell

Comment: thank you for your reply. i would like to do which the row i selected can be deleted and copied. if i click the copyBtn it should be paste under the cell which clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It deletes the first row in the first section in because you told the function to delete such an indexPath `indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)`

Second you need to save which indexPath to copy/delete when an indexPath is selected
In your view controller have a variable:

```
var SelectedIndexPath = IndexPath
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     SelectedIndexPath = indexPath
}

@IBAction func didTapDeleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("didTapDeleteBtn")
    YOUR_MODEL.remove(at: SelectedIndexPath.row)// if your model is just an array
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [SelectedIndexPath], with: .fade)
    //tableView.reloadData()// You normally do not need reloadData() if you use tableView.deleteRows

}

@IBAction func didTapCopyBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("didTapCopyBtn")
    dataAry.append[dataAry[SelectedIndexPath]]
    tableView.reloadRows(at: SelectedIndexPath, with: .none)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the index path of the cell tapped to be able to infer which cell to append under or delete.

The best way to do this is to handle the button press in the cell, then call a delegate which you set as the view controller in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  See here: [Remove cell when button pressed inside cell CustomTableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242514/remove-cell-when-button-pressed-inside-cell-customtableviewcell)

Here's some sample code.  Also notice you don't need to call `reloadData()` if you tell your table view you're updating it and you're finished updating it.  This will be significantly more performant, as you do not need to reload every cell to update one.

```swift
// Inside your cell's class
@IBAction func didTapDeleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.deleteButtonWasTappedIn(cell: self)
}

// Inside your view controller
func deleteButtonWasTappedIn(cell: YourCustomCellClass) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)], with: .fade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: means i need to add a new button into my customtableviewcell ?

Comment: You need to place the delete and copy buttons inside your custom table view cell and set the actions for those buttons inside that class.  When someone tap's the button, you call the delegate (your view controller) to be able to alter the table view, as shown above.

Comment: thank you for your reply. what i wan to do is when i select cell then the button will show up and click the button is will be deleted and copied is not inside the tableviewcell

Comment: Sammy's answer is what you want, then.

Comment: Although I would highly suggest that instead of doing this yourself, you use the `UITableView` `isEditing` mode.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614876-setediting